# Sorting and grouping lines with if construction

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

This is my input file

```
otf.msn.com
otf.msn.com
accounts.google.com
Email=adresemail@gmail.com
www.x-kom.pl
login=przykladowyuzytkownik
allegro.pl
ssl.allegro.pl
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
store.steampowered.com
username=steamuser
logowanie.interia.pl
login.live.com
login=mailhotmail@hotmail.com
www.bing.com
```

I need to make relations with username/user/login and the site address.
Site address is always line above the user/email/login. The condition could be `=` sign.

If line contains `=` 
then this line = user
     line above (line-1) = site

What i want is a file with users and sites connected.
Output can be a txt file. User and site can be in like in one line f.e

```
accounts.google.com - Email = adresmail@gmail.com
```

or like in my input file

```
accounts.google.com 
Email=adresmail@gmail.com
store.steampowered.com
username=steamuser
```

QUESTION IS : How can i make this condition? 
I mean i'm new in awk/grep/sed and not sure how to build an if condition.
How can i get the line above the line which include `=` / how to make the relation beetwen line with `=` and line above?
IN SHORT 
group every line which include `=` with the line above. Output this to file.

Thanks :)

Comment: How on earth are you supposed to know which email matches which site?

Comment: You have asked a few similar questions. You clearly will have to provide more explicit requirements. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: as i said, email/username match with site above (line before). Its about matching lines with usernames/logins/mails with the line upper.

Comment: The question is: what is the question? Try to add a question sign anywhere.

Comment: This seems to be the 5th time you've asked essentially the same question with slight tweaks to your requirements each time and you haven't accepted an answer for any of the previous 4. I don't expect things will go any better this time around. I don't understand why you can't just post **A QUESTION** with whatever your requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

`$ grep = input.txt  -B1 | grep -v -e "--" | sed "N;s/\n/ - /"`

Comment: Would be a problem for you to describe how it work? It would take me a lot of time to find how every command works

Comment: Now that's just lazy.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/=/{print p "\t" $0} {p=$0}' file | column -t

accounts.google.com     Email=adresemail@gmail.com
www.x-kom.pl            login=przykladowyuzytkownik
store.steampowered.com  username=steamuser
login.live.com          login=mailhotmail@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is worth to answer this question the way it has been "asked", but it satisfies my necrophiliac passion to hack `sed`. So forgive me that I could not resist to answer this.

```
#! /bin/sh
sed -n "
/^Email/{
 H;g;s/\nEmail=/ /p
}
h" <<EOF
otf.msn.com
otf.msn.com
accounts.google.com
Email=adresemail@gmail.com
www.x-kom.pl
login=przykladowyuzytkownik
allegro.pl
ssl.allegro.pl
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
store.steampowered.com
username=steamuser
logowanie.interia.pl
login.live.com
login=mailhotmail@hotmail.com
www.bing.com
EOF
```

Output is:

```
accounts.google.com adresemail@gmail.com
```

If the line starts with `Email` append pattern space to hold space, copy hold space into pattern space, replace keyword and print the result. Next copy hold space to pattern space.